# Error: Must call google.charts.load before google.charts.setOnLoadCallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have the following imports in HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

And some of my js code:

```
// load google charts library
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// for rest, walk, fast_walk data
var data, options, chart;

var i = 0;

/* initialize chart1 - rest, walk, fast_walk data */
function drawChart(data, options) {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('data-container'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    return(chart);
}
```

However I am getting Error: Must call google.charts.load before google.charts.setOnLoadCallback

How can I solve this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes

> The google.charts.load() call now returns a JavaScript Promise, so in
> addition to the other callback mechanisms, you can call your chart
> drawing function like this: google.charts.load('current',
> {packages:['corechart']}).then(drawChart);

Instead of using:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Use one call to:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']}).then(drawChart);
```

Comment: More: google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'line']});

Answer (score -1):

I solved the error by removing the following code:

```
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use the callback, or you could run into other issues. The problem is your loading the old version of Google charts, but using the callback for the new version. JSAPI should no longer be used, see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) for details...

Comment: Also, you are loading both the jsapi loader and the new gstatic loader.  Jsapi will be redirected to the new loader. So you are loading the new loader twice.